# Rails: Return HTML from helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I was trying to display some font-awesome icons, when a favorite is true or either false.

I had something similar like below:

Application Controller

```
def favorite_text
    @favorite_exists ? '<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>' : '<i class="fas fa-heart-o"</i>'
end

helper_method :favorite_text
```

And in the view:

```
<%= link_to favorite_text, update_favorites_path, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the helper `html_safe` to signal that the hrml inside the string is safe and does not have to be escaped (simply speaking).

You can add this call inside your helper:

```
def favorite_text
    (@favorite_exists ? '<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>' : '<i class="fas fa-heart-o"</i>').html_safe
end
```

Then you can create a link by calling `link_to` with a block:

```
<%= link_to update_favorites_path, remote: true do %>
    <%= favorite_text %>
<% end %>
```

A more in-depth explanation can be found in the official docs: https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but none of your suggestions worked.

Comment: By "not working" you mean your tags are still escaped?

Comment: I added an alternate call to output your text. Please have a look?

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue to show ratings stars of fontawesome but figured out a way through the below helper method

```
###in my application_helper.rb

    def show_big_rating_stars(count)
    if count && count > 0
       (0...count).map { content_tag(:span, "" , class: "fa fa-star gold fa-2x") }.join  
    end    


    ###this is how use it in my views
    show_big_rating_stars(vendor.ratings.count)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but the provided code isn't really related to my current problem. imo

Comment: Well..you can change the code in the way you want..it should get your work started.